# Date elements wrap

Tags: datetime

How can i wrap date elements in this function?

```
function theme_date_display_single($variables) {
    $date = $variables['date'];
    $timezone = $variables['timezone'];
    $attributes = $variables['attributes'];
// Wrap the result with the attributes.
    return '<span class="date-display-single"' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . $date . $timezone . '</span>';
}
```

I think i can call $date with some parametrs, but don't which. I want something like:

```
return '<span class="date-display-single"' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '> <label class="day">'. $day. '</label> <label class="month">'. $month. '</label>' . $timezone . '</span>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you,

In Drupal 7 you can use [**Custom Formatters**](https://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) module for your requirement.

Steps

- Install and enable [**Custom Formatters**](https://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) and [**TOKEN**](https://drupal.org/project/token) module
- Create you own format using **admin/structure/formatters**

  [image]
- Use the available TOKENS

  [image]
- Use TOKEN and HTML TAGS to create new format

  [image]
- After creating the new format

  [image]
- Use the new date format where you want to show

  [image]